# Em R, ordenar uma data frame segundo uma coluna e por grupos

Tags: r

Eu quero ordenar uma data frame segundo uma coluna v2 e respeitando a coluna grupos. Por exemplo, suponha que eu tenho df da seguinte maneira

```
df
v1 v2 grupo
1   5   1
4   1   1
1   2   1
5   7   2
4   2   2
1   9   2
```

Eu quero que o resultado seja

```
df
v1 v2 grupo
4   1   1
1   2   1
1   5   1
4   2   2
5   7   2
1   9   2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você também pode utilizar a função **arrange** do pacote **dplyr**, que particularmente eu acho mais facil tanto na leitura como na escrita do que o jeito "normal".

Recomendo bastante o aprendizado do pacote dplyr para manipulação de dados em um dataframe.

Basta você informar o dataframe e as colunas por ordem de ordenação

```
v1 <- c(1,4,1,5,4,1)
v2 <- c(5,1,2,7,2,9)
grupo <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2)
df <- data.frame(v1,v2,grupo)

library(dplyr)

arrange(df, grupo, v2)
# v1 v2 grupo
# 4  1     1
# 1  2     1
# 1  5     1
# 4  2     2
# 5  7     2
# 1  9     2
```

Caso queira alguma por ordem decrescente, por exemplo a v2, utilize **desc**(nomeColuna):

```
arrange(df, grupo, desc(v2))
# v1 v2 grupo
# 1  5     1
# 1  2     1
# 4  1     1
# 1  9     2
# 5  7     2
# 4  2     2
```

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar `order()` com mais de uma condição, colocando as colunas em ordem de prioridade:

```
df <- read.table(text="v1 v2 grupo
                 1   5   1
                 4   1   1
                 1   2   1
                 5   7   2
                 4   2   2
                 1   9   2", header=TRUE)

df[order(df$grupo, df$v2),]    
#   v1 v2 grupo
# 2  4  1     1
# 3  1  2     1
# 1  1  5     1
# 5  4  2     2
# 4  5  7     2
# 6  1  9     2
```